# How to set Edit cursor at the end when adding new widget?

Tags: python, urwid

I'm trying to set the cursor at the end of the `Edit.edit_text` when a new `Edit` widget is added to the `ListBox`. I try to set it to the last position with the function `set_cursor_end()` at the end of `new_line()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```py
import urwid
from selectable_edit import SelectableEdit


class NewLine(urwid.ListBox):
    def __init__(self):
        body = urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker([])
        super(NewLine, self).__init__(body)

        self.current_widget = None
        self.pos = -1

        self.new_line()

    def add( self, widget) :
        self.pos += 1
        self.body.insert( self.pos, widget )
        self.set_focus( self.pos )

    def new_line( self ) :
        widget = urwid.Edit(('I say', u"What is your name?: "), "Test")
        self.current_widget = widget
        self.add( widget )
        self.set_cursor_end()

    def set_cursor_end( self ):
        text = self.current_widget.edit_text
        self.current_widget.edit_pos = len( text )

    def set_cursor_begin( self ):
        self.current_widget.edit_pos = 0

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        key = super(NewLine, self).keypress(size, key)
        if key == 'tab' or key == 'ctrl right':
            self.set_cursor_end()
        elif key == 'ctrl left':
            self.set_cursor_begin()
        elif key != 'enter':
            return key
        else :
            self.new_line()


palette = [('I say', 'default,bold', 'default'),]
urwid.MainLoop(NewLine(), palette).run()
```

In this example, the last widget is focused when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but the cursor positions is always the same as before, and not the end of the line.

Also, `set_cursor_end()` works when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed.